# Mais uma pergunta fechada como off-topic

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, escopo-do-site

Porque é que esta pergunta [Instrução para adicionar valor no AX](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/59702/ajuda-em-assembly) está fechada como *off-topic*?

Agora fecha-se tudo como *off-topic*?

Comment: Só não coloquei para reabrir porque a pergunta precisa de ser melhorada...

Comment: É verdade, outras vezes vi perguntas e estava elaborando a resposta, quando fui postar a pergunta já tinha sido fechada. Quase virou uma briga. Acredito que quando uma pergunta fosse fechar, poderia colocar uma tag nela de revisão e notificar o autor para melhorar a pergunta, dando um prazo máximo de 2h. Mas claro, se a pergunta não tiver nada a ver com o SO, fecha de uma vez.

Comment: foi descuido de minha parte, o ator veio com uma pergunta que era um exercício de um livro, mas não apresentou detalhes, segurei um pouco antes de fechar, mas como ele não apresentou o esforço esperado deduzi que um pedido de "faça isto pra  mim" não é uma pergunta "sobre programação" e por este motivo fechei (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/59700/3635), claro que posso ter me enganado nisto também e por causa da primeira acabei fechando a que você se refere, pois pensei se tratar da mesma situação. Por favor, se a primeira também for valida me comunique, irei votar para reabrir. Grato.